# Using "en" with the verb "être"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes, en

The pronoun *en* can be used to replace indefinite nouns.

> Tu as mangé du riz ce matin ?
>
> Oui, j'**en** ai mangé.

Does this usage still work if the verb is *être*?

> C'est un canard ?
>
> Oui, c'**en** est un.

I know that the verb *être* is often an exception, so I'm not sure if the pronoun *en* can be used in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using *en* with *être* is perfectly correct and idiomatic:

> — C'est un canard ?
>
> — Oui, c'en est un.

The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c') gives that example:

> - avec le pron. en. C'en est :
>
>   - 32. Lahirel, en toilette du matin, un petit peigne d'une main, et de l'autre, un miroir dans lequel il se regarde. (...) Voyons donc! c'en est bien un... c'en est même trois! Il arrache un ou deux cheveux. Pailleron, L'Âge ingrat,1879, I, 1, p. 1.
> - Rem. Loc. c'en est fait. Cf. faire.

Other common sentences using *en* with *être*:

> — *Il en est* (he is one of them).
>
> — *Nous en sommes capables* (we are able to do it).

Note that in your last sentences, ***c'*** is a ***ce***, not ***cela*** otherwise the question would have been the stilted :

> — Cela est est un canard ?
>
> — Oui, cela en est un.

Comment: Thanks! In the example "c'en est bien un... c'en est même trois!", what is the thing that *un* and *trois* refer to? From the context I guess it's gray hair?

Comment: Gray hairs indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Le verbe être fonctionne parfaitement dans ce cas.
"C'en est" est la forme contractée de "Cela en est".

Si vous voulez d'autres exemples dites moi

Comment: Oui, d'autres exemples seraient utiles, merci.

Comment: @user11550 : "En est" correspond souvent à la phrase que vous avez cité

Comment: Je peux vous donner plus d'exemples mais ils seront similaires à ceux déjà donnés

Comment: One other example I like: http://www.wordreference.com/fren/j'en%20suis. E.g. from the last stanza of this Hugo poem: http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/victor_hugo/ultima_verba.html