# Using an indefinite article to declare one's profession when using “en” with the verb “être”

Tags: articles, professions, en

This question is prompted by (and I see it more as a combination, rather than a mere duplicate of) the following questions previously asked on this forum:

[this older one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/962/peut-on-dire-je-suis-fran%C3%A7ais-je-suis-peintre-etc) with recent activity concerning
 **the lack of indefinite articles when announcing/declaring one’s profession**
 (e.g., “Je suis peintre”)

and [this newer one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23722/using-en-with-the-verb-%C3%AAtre) concerning “**[the use of] “en” with the verb “être.**”

Taking “advocat” and “Je suis advocat” as an example of describing or declaring one’s profession, I’ve witnessed on several occasions anglophone lawyers being [good-naturedly] questioned by French speakers if they truly meant to say:
 “I am an **advocado**” when announcing “Je suis **un** avocat”
 because otherwise they should have said simply “Je suis avocat” to let it be known that they are lawyers.

Although I seriously doubt that the simple inclusion of the “un” in the above exchange does, in fact, change the meaning as drastically as my nit-picking French wife^^ would have me believe, it does make me wonder if the indefinite article should (or at least can) also be omitted by a fellow lawyer who wants to respond using the “J’**en suis** [un?] aussi” construction to say:
 “Moi aussi [je suis avocat, moi aussi]”?

---

In short:
1)  Would **“J’en suis, aussi”** in response to “Je suis avocat” (or any profession where the indefinite article is omitted) be correct, or can/should one include the article (i.e., “J’en suis **un**, aussi”) without fear, in the case of a lawyer, of the “un” transforming “avocat” to mean the main ingredient of guacamole? And, of course;
2)  Why and/or why not?

(^^the said nit-picker says she’d avoid the issue altogether by using “Je suis avocat/e aussi” or simply “Moi aussi” but if pressed to use “en+être,” she’d use “J’en suis **un/e** aussi,” but was unable to provide any logical explanation of why the omission/inclusion of the article has meaning in the initial declaration but not in the response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "un" doesn't really change the meaning (everyone will understand you). However, in France, "Je suis avocat" is more used than "Je suis un avocat" (because "Je suis un avocat" means that you are a lawyer among many others and "Je suis avocat" just means that your profession is lawyer). Moreover, someone who is also a lawyer will simply respond with "Moi aussi" to "Je suis avocat".

Answer (score 1):

Listen to your nit-picker. Everything she said is correct.

> J’en suis, aussi

Makes no sense.

You could use the following. Among others.

> Je suis avocat -> Je le suis aussi / moi aussi.
>   Je suis un avocat -> j'en suis un aussi

Comment: *J'en suis, aussi* might be an humorous way to answer to *je suis un avocat* ("I'm in, too".)